# Trying to get HTTP POST request in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, http-headers, firefox-addon

I'm building an extension to get the POST request in Firefox. I read through the documentation for intercepting page loads and HTTP observers, but still couldn't manage to get the specific POST data on a page load (ex: data1=50&sdata2=0&data3=50).

I looked into TamperData's code, and found that they used stream.available() and stream.read(1). However, I couldn't get these commands to work with my code.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var ObserverTest = {
```

`observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
        if (topic == 'http-on-modify-request') {
            var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
        }
        if (topic == "http-on-examine-response") {
            var newListener = new TracingListener();
            subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
            newListener.originalListener = subject.setNewListener(newListener);
        }
    },

    register: function() {
        var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
        observerService.addObserver(ObserverTest, "http-on-modify-request", false);
        observerService.addObserver(ObserverTest, "http-on-examine-response", false);
    },
    unregister: function() {
        var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
        observerService.removeObserver(ObserverTest, "http-on-modify-request");
        observerService.removeObserver(ObserverTest,"http-on-examine-response");
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", ObserverTest.register, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", ObserverTest.unregister, false);


//Helper function for XPCOM instanciation (from Firebug)
function CCIN(cName, ifaceName) {
    return Cc[cName].createInstance(Ci[ifaceName]);
}
// Copy response listener implementation.
function TracingListener() {
    this.originalListener = null;
    this.receivedData = [];   // array for incoming data.
}

TracingListener.prototype = {
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        var binaryInputStream = CCIN("@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1", "nsIBinaryInputStream");
        var storageStream = CCIN("@mozilla.org/storagestream;1", "nsIStorageStream");
        var binaryOutputStream = CCIN("@mozilla.org/binaryoutputstream;1", "nsIBinaryOutputStream");


        var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);
        stream.init(binaryInputStream);

        binaryInputStream.setInputStream(inputStream);
        storageStream.init(8192, count, null);
        binaryOutputStream.setOutputStream(storageStream.getOutputStream(0));

        // Copy received data as they come.
        var data = binaryInputStream.readBytes(count);
        this.receivedData.push(data);

        binaryOutputStream.writeBytes(data, count);

        this.originalListener.onDataAvailable(request, context, storageStream.newInputStream(0), offset, count);
    },

    onStartRequest: function(request, context) {
        this.originalListener.onStartRequest(request, context);
    },

    onStopRequest: function(request, context, statusCode)
    {
        // Get entire response
        var responseSource = this.receivedData.join();
        this.originalListener.onStopRequest(request, context, statusCode);
    },

    QueryInterface: function (aIID) {
        if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIStreamListener) || aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
            return this;
        }
        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `"http-on-examine-response"` and `TracingListener` isn't required at all. This stuff would have merit if you wanted to do something with the response, but you're after data in the request, so `topic == 'http-on-modify-request'` it is.

The following function (untested, but copied from one of my extensions and cleaned up a bit)  demonstrates how to get post data. The function is assumed to be called from `http-on-modify-request`.

```
const ScriptableInputStream = Components.Constructor(
  "@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1",
  "nsIScriptableInputStream",
  "init");

function observeRequest(channel, topic, data) {
  let post = null;

  if (!(channel instanceof Ci.nsIHttpChannel) ||
    !(channel instanceof Ci.nsIUploadChannel)) {
    return post;
  }
  if (channel.requestMethod !== 'POST') {
    return post;
  }

  try {
    let us = channel.uploadStream;
    if (!us) {
      return post;
    }
    if (us instanceof Ci.nsIMultiplexInputStream) {
      // Seeking in a nsIMultiplexInputStream effectively breaks the stream.
      return post;
    }
    if (!(us instanceof Ci.nsISeekableStream)) {
      // Cannot seek within the stream :(
      return post;
    }

    let oldpos = us.tell();
    us.seek(0, 0);

    try {
      let is = new ScriptableInputStream(us);

      // we'll read max 64k
      let available = Math.min(is.available(), 1 << 16);
      if (available) {
        post = is.read(available);
      }
    }
    finally {
      // Always restore the stream position!
      us.seek(0, oldpos);
    }
  }
  catch (ex) {
    Cu.reportError(ex);
  }
  return post;
}
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to check if the `us instanceof` e.g. `nsIMIMEInputStream` or `nsIStringInputStream` for special handling or fast-paths...

You'd call it from your observer like:

```
  observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
    if (topic == 'http-on-modify-request') {
      observeRequest(subject, topic, data);
    }
  },
```

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. When you say the function observeRequest is called from http-on-modify-request, do you mean within the     observe: function(subject, topic, data) {...} I have in ObserverTest?
Also, I'm not entirely sure what to pass in for the three parameters channel, topic, and data.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more precise here. Updated my answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. Thanks a whole bunch! I'll add the working code as an edit in the question if anyone else needs it. 
edit: nevermind, you did that already XD

Comment: If I needed edit the POST data before it gets sent, how much of the code would get changed?

Comment: Depends on what you would like to change... In general you'll need to call [`setUploadStream`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsIUploadChannel.idl#48) with the new data. If you need to know anything more than this, post a new question.

Comment: Your code worked for me after it changed the definition of the constants to the following: `const {Cc,CC,Ci,Cr,Components} = require("chrome");
const ScriptableInputStream = CC("@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1","nsIScriptableInputStream","init");` Could that be connected to [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=825947) bug report?

Comment: I wrote *plain* code, because that is what I normally do, not the SDK-have-to-require-chrome-cannot-use-Constructor variant (this is where the bug you mentioned comes into play), as there is no indication in your question that you're using the SDK... So yes, the SDK way is to require `chrome` and not use `Constructor` due to the bug.